# How to Navigate to the LoginScreen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-navigation

I am having issues with Navigating to the LoginScreen. Here are the two modules, first is the welcome_screen.dart module, and 2nd is the login_screen.dart module. I am facing an error. I am unable to navigate to the 2nd screen. i.e. the login_screen.dart. I hope I have written the code properly. It's causing a lot of issues in navigating and routing.

welcome_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/signup_screen.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => WelcomeScreenState();
}
class WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children:  <Widget> [
            const Text("Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
            Image.asset("assets/images/girl-icon.jpg", height: 200,),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 50),
                        minimumSize: const Size(500, 50),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          letterSpacing: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const LoginScreen()));
                      },
                      child: const Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ), )),
                )),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom( padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 50),
                  shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))),
                    minimumSize: const Size(375, 50),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const SigninScreen()));
                  },
                  child: const Text("SignUp")),)
          ],
        ),
        heightFactor: 30,
      ),
    );
  }}
```

login_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/welcome_screen.dart';

class LoginScreen extends WelcomeScreen{
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children:  <Widget>[
      const Text("LOGIN",
      ),
      const TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
           border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
      ),
      Image.asset("assets/images/girl-icon.png")
    ],
  ));
 }
}
```

Comment: your code seems like ok, what was the issue you got?

Comment: I was getting an error, I was getting a glitch when I was clicking on the buttons. The screen was shaking. Well, my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LoginScreen.dart` extends `WelcomeScreen` then how navigator will work??
Your `LoginScreen.dart` must have `Stateful` or `Stateless` screen then you can easily navigate your Welcome screen to Login.

Ex:-`class LoginScreen extends Steteless` (Or make it Stateful as per your need)

Comment: Well, `class LoginScreen extends WelcomeScreen` worked for me.